# How to deploy ASP.NET application to production machine without having to change DB connection string manually

Tags: c#, asp.net

As it stands, right now when I deploy my web application I always go into my web.config file to change the server name etc from the connection string manually before deploying the application.  Is there an easier way to deploy a web app without having to always change the server in the connection string?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to deploy at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project:

[How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Project Deployment Using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I get voted down when I post answers like this with just a link. And now the link is not supported and out of date.

Comment: Both links work for me. Which link is "out of date" and why?

Comment: You don't see the message at the top of those pages saying _We're no longer updating this content regularly._? The problem with the _How to: Transform Web.config_ article is that _If no transform file exists_ ... _right-click the Web.config file_ does not work. I have posted an answer that I hope helps others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are deploying your web app, but one common way to do it is to use web.config transforms

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

we use [WIX installer](http://wixtoolset.org/) exactly for this purpose.

It can be customized, like in my case, to select DEV, QA or PROD env while installation.

Best thing is it uses underlying MSI installation framework, if thats the right word here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need to change the connection string for just one specific Web Deploy then you can do that with a transformation as others have said. The following should show exactly what you need to do.

In Solution Explorer expand the Properties node to get the PublishProperties as in the following.

[image]

Right-click on the Web Deploy profile and select *Add Config Transform* as shown in the following.

[image]

You will get a *Web.project - Web Deploy.config* file in the Web Config node. The initial contents will be the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <!--
      In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of 
      "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator 
      finds an attribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyDB" 
          connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
          xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
      </connectionStrings>
-->
<system.web>
  <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  <!--
    In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
    <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
    Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
    <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
      mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
  -->
</system.web>
```

Change the sample to the following or add the following.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="csname"
    connectionString="yourotherconnectionstring"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Where *csname* is the name in the Web.config of your connection string that you need to replace in the deployment.

There are many other transformations possible but if you only need to change the connection string for a specific Web Deploy then that should be the most straight forward. It is saying that you want to search for the connection string that has the specified name and then change the connection string value during the deployment.